GridDB_Python - Error: GSException during Put_Container
I'm encountering an error when trying to insert and select data using the GridDB Python client. Here's the code snippet:
import griddb_python as griddb
import datetime

factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
gridstore = factory.get_store(
    host='127.0.0.1', 
    port=20001, 
    cluster_name='myCluster',
    username='admin', 
    password='admin'
)

conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo(
    name="iot_sensor",
    column_info_list=[
        ["iot_timestamp", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
        ["iot_id", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["iot_value", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]
    ],
    type=griddb.ContainerType.TIME_SERIES,
    row_key=True)

ts = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)
ts.put([datetime.datetime.now(), "sensor003", 432.51])
ts.put([datetime.datetime.now(), "sensor004", 528.27])

rs = ts.query("SELECT * FROM iot_sensor")
rs = query.fetch()

while rs.has_next():
    data = rs.next()
    print(data)
    
gridstore.close()


Error Message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/MyData/GridDB/pycode/insert.py", line 23, in <module>
    ts = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)
  File "/home/deekey/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/griddb_python.py", line 747, in put_container
    return _griddb_python.Store_put_container(self, info, modifiable)
griddb_python.GSException


I got an empty message when printing the exception using this code snippet:
try:
    ts = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)
    ts.put([datetime.datetime.now(), "sensor003", 432.51])
    ts.put([datetime.datetime.now(), "sensor004", 528.27])

    rs = ts.query("SELECT * FROM iot_sensor")
    rs = query.fetch()

    while rs.has_next():
        data = rs.next()
        print(data)
except griddb.GSException as e:
    print(e)


Steps Taken:

Installed griddb-python following the official guide: https://pypi.org/project/griddb-python/
Verified connection details (host, port, cluster name, username, password) using gs_sh and SQL Workbench. Both tools successfully connect and perform SQL operations on the container "iot_sensor".

gs_sh output:
gs[public]> showtable
Database : public
Name                 Type        PartitionId
---------------------------------------------
iot_sensor           COLLECTION           30

 Total Count: 1

gs[public]> select * from iot_sensor;
2 results. (2 ms)
gs[public]>


SQL Workbench output:
SQL> WbConnect -driver=com.toshiba.mwcloud.gs.sql.Driver -driverJar=/usr/share/java/gridstore-jdbc.jar -url=jdbc:gs://127.0.0.1:20001/myCluster/public -username=admin -password=admin;

Connection to "User=admin, URL=jdbc:gs://127.0.0.1:20001/myCluster/public" successful

SQL> select * from iot_sensor;

iot_timestamp       | iot_id    | iot_value
--------------------+-----------+----------
2024-09-07 23:57:46 | sensor001 |    234.32
2024-09-07 23:58:23 | sensor002 |     83.98

(2 Rows)
SELECT executed successfully


Environment:
WSL using GridDB version 5.5
I am not sure, what I am missing here.

Finally I found a successful connection method, from the code snippet in the 'Build an App' section for Java (link here), and unfortunately it is not explained in the 'Build an App' section for python. The user property needs to be changed to username to work in griddb-python. For the correct connection, please see the following code snippet:
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1:10001"
DB_CLUSTER = "myCluster"
DB_USER = "admin"
DB_PASS = "admin"

gridstore = factory.get_store(
    notification_member=DB_HOST, cluster_name=DB_CLUSTER, username=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS)

With the necessary adjustments to the original code, here is the python code for griddb that runs without errors
import griddb_python as griddb
import datetime

# Connect to Griddb cluster
factory = griddb.StoreFactory.get_instance()
DB_HOST = "127.0.0.1:10001"
DB_CLUSTER = "myCluster"
DB_USER = "admin"
DB_PASS = "admin"

gridstore = factory.get_store(
    notification_member=DB_HOST, cluster_name=DB_CLUSTER, username=DB_USER, password=DB_PASS)

# Create a container for storing data
conInfo = griddb.ContainerInfo(
    name="iot_sensor",
    column_info_list=[
        ["iot_timestamp", griddb.Type.TIMESTAMP],
        ["iot_id", griddb.Type.STRING],
        ["iot_value", griddb.Type.DOUBLE]
    ],
    type=griddb.ContainerType.TIME_SERIES,
    row_key=True)
ts = gridstore.put_container(conInfo)

# Insert data into Griddb
ts.put([datetime.datetime.now(), "sensor003", 432.51])
ts.put([datetime.datetime.now(), "sensor004", 528.27])

# Select data from Griddb
query = ts.query("SELECT * FROM iot_sensor")
rs = query.fetch()

while rs.has_next():
    data = rs.next()
    print(data)
    
# Close connection
gridstore.close()

